# how to sort specific div content from jquery $.post

Tags: jquery, post

I am getting data from following jquery post method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.post("page2.php",function(data){
   $("#content").html(data);
 });
  });
```

By the above method, I can get whole html of page2.php. But I want only content of div id="abc". How can I get by processing data from jquery $.post?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to parse and explore the HTML:

```
$($.parseHTML(data)).find('#abc')
```

Comment: How can I then place parseHTML data to page1.php's div id #content